# Как найти начало последней строки в файле?

Tags: java

Задача: Найти начало (номер байта) последней строки в файле. С помощью `FileChannel` берём по порции байтов с конца файла и всё вроде бы работает.

```java
    public long findingStartLastLine(){
    //How many bytes to take from line
    byte[] buffer = new byte [41];
    long position=0;
            try {
                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r");
                FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
                ByteBuffer arrayBytes = ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer);
                Path filePath = Paths.get(path);
                long size = Files.size(filePath);
                position=size-buffer.length;
                long pointer=0;
                String line;
                
                //finding position beginning line from end to file 
                while(position>0) {
                    channel.read(arrayBytes, position);
                    line = new String(buffer);
                    line=line.trim();
                    pointer+=line.length();
                    position=size-pointer;
                    if(line.indexOf("\n")!=-1) {
                        position=pointer-line.indexOf("\n");
                        raf.seek(size-position);
                        line=raf.readLine();
                        position=raf.getFilePointer();
                        break;
                    }
                arrayBytes.clear();
                }
                if(position<0)
                position=0;
                raf.seek(position);
                line = raf.readLine();
                channel.close(); raf.close();
                String utf8 = new String(line.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("UTF-8: " + utf8);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return position;
    }
```

Проблема заключается в строке `line=line.trim();` Если во время чтения очередной порции байтов курсор встанет перед началом слова, захватив пробел между предыдущим словом, то после обрезания пробелов `pointer` будет неправильно считать позицию. Если убрать `trim()`, то может получиться ситуация - буфер больше длины строки. В итоге лишние пробелы и неправильный расчёт позиции... Как можно обыграть данную ситуацию и найти начало последней строки в файле, чтоб не считать по 1 байту?

Answer (score 0):

```
String inString =  "One. Ywo.  three. Four.";
        int  lastpoint =  inString.lastIndexOf(".");
        String buf  =  inString.substring(0, lastpoint);
        System.out.println(buf.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Я все таки наверное не правильно понял задачу. Не понятно. Если все строки заканчиваются точкой, все строки и последняя,то что мешает найти последнюю точку и предпоследнюю? Можно просто удалить последнюю точку и тогда предпоследняя точка будет последней.  И от этой точки взять те самые байты

Comment: Вы всё правильно поняли и дали правильный ответ. Однако, у меня таблица индексов, а разделитель между строками System.lineSeparator(). По идее, ситуация которую я описал, не должна произойти.